# java Сериализация

Tags: java, сериализация

Добрый день. 
Изучаем сериализацию. В данном случае, надо поставить запрет сериализации.
Так вот, почему если поставить у SubSolution.writeObject модификатор доступа public, то сериализация пройдет ? 
Что-то не могу понять. Буду благодарен за ссылку на похожий вопрос или статью/литературу.

```
public class TestFile implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream("FilePath");
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);
        SubSolution subSolution = new SubSolution();
        outputStream.writeObject(subSolution);
        fileOutput.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
    public static class SubSolution extends TestFile {
        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream objectOutput) throws Exception {
            throw new NotSerializableException();
        }
        private  void readObject(ObjectInputStream objectInput) throws Exception {
            throw new NotSerializableException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам запрещать сериализацию?

Comment: Мне ? Незачем! Это просто учебное задание.) И интересует ответ на конкретный вопрос.)

Comment: Но теоретически, мы наследуемся от класса, у которого разрешена сериализация, а вот в подклассе она должна быть запрещена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации на [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) написано:

> Классы, требующие специальной обработки в процессе сериализации и десериализации
>   должны реализовывать специальные методы с в точности такими сигнатурами:
>
> ```
>  private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
>      throws IOException
>  private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
>      throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
>  private void readObjectNoData()
>      throws ObjectStreamException;
> ```

Данные методы вызываются через reflection, соответствующие объекты `Method` [заполняются](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.java/#494) с учетом требований выше. При замене `private` на `public` метод не считается подходящим и игнорируется.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.